# inconsistent accessibility property type is less accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just a little problem I build context class for migrations and database this is my context class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLayer
{
  public    class MydbContext:DbContext
    {
      public  DbSet<group_page> Group_Pages { get; set; }
      public  DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
      public  DbSet<camment_page> camment_Pages { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and after the Create data base I want create Interface I realized who I forget public my class
when I public my class prop is error in they Name and

```
inconsistent accessibility property type is less accessible
```

now I do not know  can I fix this problem without deleting my context and migrations ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLayer
{
    class group_page
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="topic")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="pleas insert {0} ")]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string groupTitle { get; set; }

        ///navigation proprty
        ///

        public virtual List<Page> Page { get; set; }

        public group_page()
        {

        }
    }
```

and this is migrations classes

```
namespace DataLayer.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataLayer.Context.MydbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(DataLayer.Context.MydbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to make your class `public`?

Comment: yes i want public my class and  all my prop is error                                       
           inconsistent accessibility property type is less accessible

Comment: Your posted class does not look like it is public.

Comment: Please post the definitions of your other classes like `group_page`, `camment_page`, `Page` etc

Comment: Make your class public, it should work.

Comment: Also, please clean up the names of those classes- there are ways to tell EF about table names that do not follow c# standards - in c# `ClassNames` `LookLike` `This`, they `do_not` `look_like` `this`

Comment: Your error message is incomplete. Post the full error. Also post your other classes

Answer (score 2):

Your other classes that appear in the DbSet brackets are not public

e.g you have

```
class Page ...
```

You cannot use this in a prop like:

```
public class Whatever{
  public DbSet<Page> ...
```

Without generating a "property type is less accessible"

See this fiddle [for example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/STkp2M) shows the error, and then watch the error go away when you make `class X` into `public class X`